# Python logger handler config for exception logging

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, exception

I have written this piece of code to get namespace from xml document.
I am trying to handle exception, and write full trace to the log. however trace is not getting written with custom message in log (though i can see it on screen).

I believe, i am missing somthing in Logger handler config. is there any specific configuration we need to deal with? below is my logger config so far.

Any help will be appreciated.!

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
hdlr = logging.FileHandler(r'C:\link.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def get_ns(xmlroot):
    """Retrieve XML Document Namespace """
    try:
        logger.info("Trying to get XML namespace detail")
        nsmap = xmlroot.nsmap.copy()
        logger.info("Creating XML Namespace Object, {0}".format(nsmap))
        nsmap['xmlns'] = nsmap.pop(None)
    except (KeyError, SystemExit):
        logging.exception("XML files does not contain namespace, Halting Program! ")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        for ns in nsmap.values():
            logger.info("Retrieved XML Namespace {0}".format(ns))
            return ns
```

output on screen:

```
ERROR:root:XML files does not contain namespace, Halting Program! 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\link.log", line 28, in get_ns
    nsmap['xmlns'] = nsmap.pop(None)
KeyError: None
```

Comment: Can edit your question to contain the traceback that you see on screen?

Comment: @Odysseas: I have updated question with screen output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
logging.exception("XML files does not contain namespace, Halting Program! ")
```

to

```
logger.exception("XML files does not contain namespace, Halting Program! ")
```

Since it's `logger` that you have configured to write to file `C:\link.log`.

Using [`logging.exception`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.exception) uses the "root logger", which outputs to the console by default.